# DB2 JDBC Create clob error

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, clob

I am using the db2jcc driver FIX Pack 6 of the 9 series.

My code

```
public void setParamsPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement s, String[][] params) throws Exception {
  ...
  Clob myClob = s.getConnection().createClob();
  myClob.setString(1, params[i][0]);

  s.setClob(i+1, myClob);
```

In JBoss 5.1.0 GA it throws the error:

```
12:01:54,914 242266 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] (ConsumerMessageQueue:(1):) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Unexpected Error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedConnectionJDK5.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
    at database.Executer.setParamsPreparedStatement(Executer.java:761)
```

In plain java it gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
    at TestClob.main(TestClob.java:20)
```

What is the cause?

Comment: Which version of JBoss AS are you using, and which binary did you download?

Comment: `createClob()` was added in JDBC 4.0 / Java 6, most likely you are using a JDBC 3.0 driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience the `createClob()` call is not needed at all. Just use `PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream()`

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into clob_table (id, clob_colum) values (?,?)";
String clobData = "....";
Reader reader = new StringReader(clobData);
pstmt.setInt(1, 42);
pstmt.setCharacterStream(2, reader, clobData.length());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I have found this to be the only cross-DBMS/JDBC solution to handle CLOBs (and BLOBs in a similar manner).