# using CLOB in java throwing exception

Tags: java, jdbc, clob

I am inserting clob data into mysql database...here is my code

```
Clob cl=dbCon.createClob();
cl.setString(1,userAbout);
dbCon.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement insertClob=dbCon.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_data SET user_about=? WHERE user_id=?");
insertClob.setClob(1,cl);
insertClob.setInt(2,userId);
int count= insertClob.executeUpdate();
if(count==1){dbCon.commit();dbCon.close();out.write("success");}
else{dbCon.rollback();dbCon.close();out.print("error");}
```

this is throwing an exception

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
```

whats the problem here? and How can I solve it?

Comment: How are you creating the dbConnection?

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: using connection pooling Connection dbCon = DBConnection.getDBConnection();

Comment: How to know what JDBC driver I am using?

Comment: have you tried getting around this by using the solution defined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724971/db2-jdbc-create-clob-error ? short version - dont use createClob(), use PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream()

Comment: @vikas devde - unless there's a root cause to this exception that you didnt post, its the not driver throwing this exception, but rather the tomcat connection pool (which wraps around the driver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `createClob()` anyway. I find using setCharacterStream() to be much more stable (and much better supported by all JDBC drivers).

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(userAbout);
PreparedStatement insertClob = dbCon.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_data SET user_about=? WHERE user_id=?");
insertClob.setCharacterStream(1, reader, userAbout.length());
insertClob.setInt(2,userId);

int count= insertClob.executeUpdate();
```

This also works with an `INSERT` statement. No need to create any intermediate clob (or blob) objects.

Note that I changed the wrong index `8` to the correct index `2` to match the placeholders in the `UPDATE` statement.

Many modern drivers also handle a "simple" `setString()` just as well for CLOB columns. It's worth trying out - would reduce the code even more.