# Exception while using .setClob()

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, clob

I want to insert a String via a Java Program into `Oracle DB` in a table having column type as `CLOB`. I am using the following code

```
 PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Json_Test values(?,?)");
 stmt.setInt(1,counter);
 stmt.setClob(2,new StringReader(s));
```

But while executing i am getting an Exception: `java.lang.Exception: 1 - oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setClob(ILjava/io/Reader;`

Comment: Answer is moved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123932/how-to-use-setclob-in-preparedstatement-injdbc

Comment: But why am i getting an exception while trying to use the .setClob() with Reader as the second argument.?

Comment: The second parameter is supposed to be a string instead of StringReader object.

Comment: @Nabin, not it doesn't: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob-int-java.io.Reader-

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace and the **exact** driver version

Answer (score 0):

Can you say jdbc version you are using?
It works correctly to me with

```
dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```