# Not able to update clob field in oracle

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I have a table which has a clob datatype column. From my java method, I am trying to update the clob column of a row using update statement. The query is executing without any error, but the clob is not updated.
The same code is working for insert statement.

Java Code used for updating clob column:

```
w_Sql="UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYCLOB= ? WHERE CHANGEREQD = ?";
_pstmt = openConnection().prepareStatement(w_Sql);
Reader reader = new StringReader(clobStr);
_pstmt.setCharacterStream(1, reader, clobStr.length());
```

Java Code used for inserting clob column:

```
w_Sql="INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'',?)";
_pstmt = openConnection().prepareStatement(w_Sql);
Reader reader = new StringReader(clobStr);
_pstmt.setCharacterStream(1, reader, clobStr.length());
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: `setString()` might be useful in the place of `setCharacterStream()` method, if I'm not wrong!

Comment: You can show this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123932/how-to-use-setclob-in-preparedstatement-injdbc)

Comment: `_pstmt.executeUpdate()` - at the end

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? MySQL or Oracle? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer Thanks a lot. I thought it won't work. so I didn't try. It worked!!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer you have commented on the post. You have not answered it. So not able to accept your answer.

Comment: @masonCOD, the only available answer to your question is my answer :)

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer why to use setString instead of setCharacterStream() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question for the others to take advantage, in resolving a situation similar to the OP's question.

`setString()` might be useful in the place of `setCharacterStream()`

Or as an alternate, you might otherwise opt for a solution as suggested on the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) altogether!

From the Oracle documentation:

```
Clob myClob = [CONNECTION OBJECT].createClob();
myClob.setString(1, [actual string value]);
_pstmt.setClob(1, myClob);
```

Either of the approaches should work and should enable you in updating the CLOB column in your table.