# Is it safe to use JDBC setString() to store CLOB data type with Oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, clob

I have a need to store a large string into Oracle database the length of which would be at most 10000 bytes. I understand that there is some configuration in Oracle 12c that can increase the 4000 byte limit of varchar2.  But I do not have the option to use that configuration.

So I am inclined to use the CLOB data type.  I have no previous experience in using CLOB.  So I have my concerns.

I saw the following on SO

[Java: How to insert CLOB into oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549450/java-how-to-insert-clob-into-oracle-database)

I did not want to use any oracle package to handle the CLOB type.  My question is, is the following safe enough for my purpose?

To store:

```
try {
    String myclobstring = "xx ........"; 
    String sql = "Insert into mytable (clobfield) values (?)";
    Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, myclobstring); 
    .
    .
}
```

To Retrieve:

```
try {
    String sql = "select clobfield from mytable";
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String s = result.getString ("clobfield');
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I will do that.  However, I am trying to see if there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the CLOB as a String, though using a stmt.setCharacterStream might be a bit better for something very large. Here is an example I found that shows this nicely:
[Storing Clobs](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/StoreCLOBsdataintodatabase.htm)

You can also use the java.sql.Clob if you're wanting to not use the Oracle specific code.

[From Oracle's documentation on CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/CLOB.html)
Use the java.sql.Clob and create the CLOB with the connection's createClob function.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I will post an answer as I did not see an explicit answer.  So far setString()/setString() is storing up to 10K characters into the CLOB field.  I am getting back what I am storing without a problem.

I did see the following related SO post that gives me a bit more confidence.

[How to use setClob() in PreparedStatement inJDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123932/how-to-use-setclob-in-preparedstatement-injdbc)