# Oracle insert text more than 4K characters to clob

Tags: java, oracle, text, insert, clob

There is a limitation to insert more than 4K characters into clob
The way I do it in Java is to slice the long text to chunks of 4K characters each and concatenate with to_clob() and it works fine

However, my text often includes ‘’
For example - “ abc’’def “

When the text is sliced between ‘’ the ‘’ the inserted text is incorrect…

For example - to_clob(“abc’) || to_clob(“‘def’”)
Any idea how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, describe the meaning of "incorrect". What you've showed will not work (throw ORA-01740 or ORA-01756), because Oracle's text literal should be enclosed with single quotation marks (`'`).

Comment: And concatenation will result in the same value as original text if it doesn't have special characters (for example, in range 0-8 in ascii). Check [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5131b725db6a0407ad8f136071fb767a)

Comment: Side Note: As of version 12c (released in July 2013) character data types *varcgar2, char, ...) may have a maximum length of 32767. That is if your DBA has set `max_string_size' to EXTENDED ` (Unfortunately many seem reluctant to do so - why ???) From SQLPlus run `show parameter max_string_size`. If EXTENDED you can define your column up to varchar2(32767). This seems to eliminate the need for most CLOB column declarations - not all but most.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a limitation to insert more than 4K characters into clob

No, there is not. There is a (historic) limitation of 4000 bytes in a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` data types and this includes string literals.

```
'This string literal has a 4000 byte limit.'
```

This has nothing to do with a `CLOB` data type or the `TO_CLOB` function.

> The way I do it in Java is to slice the long text to chunks of 4K characters each and concatenate with `to_clob()` and it works fine

Don't do that. Use a [bind variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123932).

```java
String your_string = "A very long string..."
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO table_name(clob_column) VALUES (?)"
);
Clob clob = connection.createClob();
clob.setString(1, your_string);
ps.setClob(1, clob);
```

or:

```java
String your_string = "A very long string..."
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO table_name(clob_column) VALUES (?)"
);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(your_string.getBytes());
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
ps.setClob(1, inputStreamReader);
```

> However, my text often includes `''` For example - `" abc''def "`
>
> When the text is sliced between `''` the `''` the inserted text is incorrect…
>
> For example - to_clob("abc') || to_clob("'def") Any idea how to solve it?

Don't slice the text.

If you are going to slice the text (don't) then you need to either not split it between two single quotes or escape the single quotes by doubling them up.